# text to top border space behave different when add image around it

Tags: html, css

here is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    #head {
        height: 50px;;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffff00;;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="head">
    logout
    <img src="/static/img/logout.png"/>
    logout
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

before i add the image, the height to top border is 0
[image]
after i add the image, there are spaces to top border
[image]

why will this happen, how can i make the after add image text has no space to the to top border.  i have used with margin and padding but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the alignment for an image is bottom which results in the situation that you are facing now. so you can set `vertical-align` as per your requirement. In your case it should be `vertical-align: top`. 
This can be done by adding css to the image or by adding attribute `align="top"` to the image tag.

**By adding CSS**

```
  #head > img
    {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

OR

**By adding attribute**

```
<img src="/static/img/logout.png" align="top"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to align image vertically,

In you case

```
#head img {vertical-align:top;}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#head {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffff00;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#head img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
  logout
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" width=30/>logout
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added align="top" to the image and then the image got close to the top border.
But please notice the distance between the image and the bottom border or other content below will become bigger in this case which makes the layout not look nice either.
Thanks